# How to modify an OpenOffice.org Draw diagram in Java?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, multimedia

I have an OpenOffice.org Draw diagram, which shows individual modules of my software.

I also have a file with information about problems in those modules (each module can be in one of 3 states: OK, ERROR, UNKNOWN).

I want to

a) color the figures in the diagram according to the information from the file (problematic modules - red, OK modules - green and all others - gray) and
b) export the diagram to an image file.

The original diagram is created manually (so that it is laid out nicely).

Question: How can I do this, preferably in Java?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Comment: I posted a project on vWorker for that - http://bit.ly/emKQNZ If you know how to do that, submit a bid there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenOffice has an official API.  You should check if it can do what you need.

If not, a reasonable way to progress would be to export to SVG, and then use a SVG library to manipulate the SVG XML as needed.

Answer (score 2):

@TRA has a good point.  On the other hand, if you're feeling brave..

Open Office files are Zipped XML.  Use a `ZipInputStream` to get access to the entries, then any of the plethora of J2SE based XML handling APIs (Sax, DOM etc.) to parse the XML.